# Can an Angular2 app consume an Angular4 library?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 app from which I want to use an external Angular4 library. What problems or issues am I likely to run into if any, and what do I need to be aware of?

Comment: Should be ok..,

Comment: Not likely to work especially when building with AOT. Angular4 introduced breaking changes from Angular2.

Comment: It will not work, but the other way around might work

Comment: Depends on whether the Angular4 library uses services (eg `Meta`) or directives that are not in Angular2.  There are [not many breaking changes](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/03/24/what-is-new-angular-4/) so you might be ok. Truth is, none of us know for sure.